# How to center text?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When using TouchDevelop for Windows Phone 7, is there a way to center text in a text box? Or, can a text box be centered on the Wall?

Comment: TouchDevelop web site: http://www.touchdevelop.com/

Answer (score 6):

You can set the alignment of the content in your TextBox using the **TextAlignment** property.

```
<TextBox TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textalignment(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Hi Jason... thanks for the response. However, I don't know of a way to do that in TouchDevelop, as we can't access the raw XAML code.